# Issue on Declaring PHP Variable

Tags: php

According to my understanding PHP has three different variable scopes as:

1. local   like   `$salt = 'x2x3x5';`
2. GLOBAL  like   `$GLOBALS['salt'] = 'x2x3x5';`
3. static  like    `static $salt = 'x2x3x5';`

But I saw on an online tutorial which the instructor declared and used a variable like below:

```
$config['salt'] = 'x2x3x5';
```

Can you please let me know what kind of variable is this? and what is it's usage? Thanks

Comment: It's an array. The variable is named `$config` and has an array key `salt` which equals `'x2x3x5'`. This has nothing to do with the variables scope.

Answer (score 2):

You have good reason to be confused in this case!
PHP has a very commonly used data structure called an array. `$config`, in your example, is a perfectly ordinary array. Arrays can allow you to address data by a shorter, easy to type name. Typically the "data" is called a value, and the shorter name you use to address it is called a "key". You can read more about arrays here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

You are likely confused because `$GLOBALS` is a *special* array. `$GLOBALS` is special because it will automatically have keys added to it whenever you declare a normal variable,
as in your example: `$salt = 'x2x3x5';`

In fact, if you run the following code:

```
$GLOBALS['salt'] = 'the salt!';
echo $salt;
```

Then you will echo 'the salt!'. This is because whenever you add a key/value pair to globals, you are ALSO creating a variable. The opposite holds true too; If run this code:

```
$salt = 'the salt!';
echo $GLOBALS['salt'];
```

then you will echo 'the salt!'. This is because when you define a variable, you ALSO define a key/value pair in the special `$GLOBALS` array.

Hope this gives you some insight!

Answer (score 1):

This is defining a key/value pair in an array. `$config` is an array, and 'salt' is one key in that array. Check out the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

This is an array .  The variable is, of the type array, with the name (reference) '$config'.  the index is 'salt'  the value is 'x2x3x5
Here are the docs

[PHP Array Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

The online docs are a good start: [Variable Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

But here's some clarification:

Everything is in the global scope for a script.

```
$salt = 'x2x3x5';
echo $GLOBALS['salt']; // outputs 'x2x3x5'
```

Until you put it into a function

```
$salt = 'x2x3x5';
function something() {
    $salt = '123';
    return $salt;
}
echo something(); // output '123'
echo $salt; // output 'x2x3x5'
```

Same if you wrap it up in a class property.

```
class something() {
    public static $salt = '123';
}

$salt = 'x2x3x5';
echo something::$salt; // output '123'
echo $salt; // output 'x2x3x5'
```

Finally `$config['salt'] = 'x2x3x5';` makes $config an array of values indexed by keys. This variable exists in the scope which is defined (so global if in the global scope, or within a function/class/method).

```
$config['salt'] = '1234';
$config['pepper'] = 'abcde';
echo $config['salt']; // output 1234
echo $config['pepper']; // output'abcde'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing array with php's variable.
Here `$config` is an array which has been defined in your current file or in some other file in your php project. Right now it may be in the other file which is making you confused. Check which files have been included in your current file (file that contains `$config['salt'] = 'x2x3x5';`) and look for a `$config` array variable in each file that comes along. I hope you'll find the file where $config variable has been defined as array.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a variable this is Array.

Array name [key] = 'value'